# Jquery Datepicker and Selector

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to make a "Dynamic" date picker, what I need to do is deactivate some days of week, based on a option from a selection. Something like: If I pick option 1 all Mondays are disabled, if I pick option 2, all Thursday are disable, and go on. I made a code that works, but only the fist time, if you change your selection, the datepicker just keep the first selected.

Those are the codes:

jQuery:

```
$('#comuna_select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Cachapoal/Codegua'){
        function DisableCodegua(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            // If day == 1 then it is MOnday
            if (day == 0 || day == 1 || day == 2 || day== 3 || day == 5 || day == 6 ) {
                return [false] ; 
            } else { 
                return [true] ;
            }
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultdate: currentDate,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-2:+2",
            beforeShowDay: DisableCodegua,
            minDate: '-1D',
            maxDate: '+45D',
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Cachapoal/Coinco'){
        function DisableCoinco(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            // If day == 1 then it is MOnday
            if (day == 0 || day == 1 || day == 2 || day== 3 || day == 4 || day == 6 ) {
                return [false] ; 
            } else { 
                return [true] ;
            }
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultdate: currentDate,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-2:+2",
            beforeShowDay: DisableCoinco,
            minDate: '-1D',
            maxDate: '+45D',
        });
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select name="comuna" class="form-control" tabindex=8 id="comuna_select" required>
  <option disabled selected style="font-color: #ccc;">Comuna</option>
  <option value="Cachapoal/Codegua">Cachapoal / Codegua</option>
  <option value="Cachapoal/Coinco">Cachapoal / Coinco</option>
</select>
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="fecha" class="form-control" tabindex=9 placeholder="Click para seleccionar fecha" required/>
```

I'm also using boostrap for this, thats what I use for the datepicker I guess.

PD: I tried to create a fiddle for this, but for some reason I cannot make it work.

Hope can you help me, thanks!

Comment: I make it work with a workaround, I will leave the answer here, maybe somebody need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I added destroy and refresh for the datepicker.

The JS:

```
$('#comuna_select').change(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
    if($(this).val() == 'Cachapoal/Codegua'){
        function DisableCodegua(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            // If day == 1 then it is Monday
            if (day == 0 || day == 1 || day == 2 || day== 3 || day == 5 || day == 6 ) {
                return [false] ; 
            } else { 
                return [true] ;
            }
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultdate: currentDate,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-2:+2",
            beforeShowDay: DisableCodegua,
            minDate: '-1D',
            maxDate: '+45D',
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Cachapoal/Coinco'){
        function DisableCoinco(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            // If day == 1 then it is Monday
            if (day == 0 || day == 1 || day == 2 || day== 3 || day == 4 || day == 6 ) {
                return [false] ; 
            } else { 
                return [true] ;
            }
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            defaultdate: currentDate,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-2:+2",
            beforeShowDay: DisableCoinco,
            minDate: '-1D',
            maxDate: '+45D',
        });
    } $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");
});
```

Now everything is working.